# How to access HTML text using selenium/python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have HTML tags as below:

```
<div class="mt-md common__EiReviewTextStyles__allowLineBreaks">
    <p class="strong">Pros</p>
    <p>This is the text to be captured</p></div>
```

I want to access the text " This is the text to be captured "  using selenium on Python.

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: There are a huge number of blogs and sites that will give you examples of web scraping. This question is not quite suitable for stackoverflow in its current form. I would suggest making an attempt at the problem and show your attempt if it doesnt work and people will help

Comment: s = """<div class="mt-md common__EiReviewTextStyles__allowLineBreaks">
    <p class="strong">Pros</p>
    <p>This is the text to be captured</p></div>"""

You can try to use BeautifulSoup

```from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
print(soup.text)
```

Comment: I have tried get_element_by_css(.mt-md...)

Comment: And then get_element_by_class_name('strong')

Comment: This gives me only 'Pros' as output. I want to get the next line too in my output

Comment: try with this xpath - this will return the text you need .  //div/p[@class='strong']/following-sibling::p/text()

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find_element_by_xpath`, like bellow:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "mt-md")]//p[@class="strong"]//following-sibling::p[text()]').text
```

Or if you want achieve all text in your `div`, use `.find_element_by_css_selector`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.mt-md.common__EiReviewTextStyles__allowLineBreaks').text
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text within the second `<p>` tag i.e. **This is the text to be captured** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.mt-md.common__EiReviewTextStyles__allowLineBreaks p:nth-of-type(2)"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `text`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mt-md common__EiReviewTextStyles__allowLineBreaks']//following-sibling::p[2]"))).text)
  ```